# How to add multiple custom buttons in one row dynamically ? [JQuery Datatables]

Tags: datatables

I am using Datatables API but am not able to add multiple buttons in one row.

```
var table = $('#table_invdata').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": -1,
        "data": null,
        "defaultContent": 
           '<button class="btn-view" type="button">EDIT</button>'              
    }]  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
var table = $('#table_invdata').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": -1,
        "data": null,
        "defaultContent": 
           '<button class="btn-view" type="button">EDIT</button>'    
           + '<button class="btn-delete"  type="button">Delete</button>'          
    }]  
});
```

Or

```
var table = $('#table_invdata').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": -1,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": 
               '<button class="btn-view" type="button">EDIT</button> <button class="btn-delete"  type="button">Delete</button>'          
        }]  
    });
```

**Update :**

You can use datatable `render` function to update the column values.

```
<table class="table" id="datatable" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name </th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Jquery Datatable Code :**

```
$('#datatable').DataTable ({
        "data" : FinalResult,
         "columns" : [
                { "data" : Name},
                { "data" : null,render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                            return '<button class="btn-view" type="button">EDIT</button>';
                        } },
                { "data" : null,render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                            return '<button class="btn-delete"  type="button">Delete</button>';
                        } }
                ]
            });
```

**Fiddel Link** : https://jsfiddle.net/jijomonkmgm/j6madey4/

Comment: Thanks for your support but I want to add buttons in different columns. Above code is adding more than one button in one column only.

Comment: @Manish.YK Can you please post your html table code

Comment: I have updated the HTML Code. I just want to add button in EMPID and POSITION on the basis of some condition.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Manish.YK I Updated my answer with some sample data, please check it

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="table_invdata" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<tr> 
<th>EmpID</th>
<th>EmpName</th>
<th>Email-id</th>
<th>Salary</th>
<th>Position</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
</table>
```